# sql managed instance authentication fails when using AAD integrated method

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs, adal, azure-sql

I have setup hybrid identity with Azure Active Directory with Federation (AD FS) method. I have created sql managed instance and added a user as Active directory Admin. Now, I tried connecting to this sql managed instance from a domain joined VM logged in as the user using AAD integrated method. The connection failed with the following error:

===================================

Cannot connect to {},3342.

===================================

One or more errors occurred. (mscorlib)

---

Program Location:

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.GetFedAuthToken(SqlFedAuthInfo fedAuthInfo)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OnFedAuthInfo(SqlFedAuthInfo fedAuthInfo)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

===================================

One or more errors occurred. (mscorlib)

---

Program Location:

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.<>c__DisplayClass134_1.b__0()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

===================================

Failed to parse XML blob.
Reason: XML document must have a top level element.
Line: 0, Position: 0
Text: (null) (System.Data)

---

Program Location:

at ADALNativeWrapper.ADALGetAccessToken(String username, IntPtr password, String stsURL, String servicePrincipalName, ValueType correlationId, String clientId, Boolean* fWindowsIntegrated, Int64& fileTime)
at System.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryNativeAuthenticationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

SSMS version(latest):15.0.18384.0
Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Just to help troubleshoot...

1. Can you connect with SQL Authentication?
2. Can you connect to other services using AAD auth?
3. Which client are you using to log in, and what are the connection settings you are using?

Comment: I can connect with "AAD - password" method. I am using SSMS with default options and set connection method to "AAD - Integrated". I have not tried AAD auth on other services. Will try and update here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error that you have received, please check whether the federated-on premises domain is configured for SSO for pass through authentication and password hash authentication. Also, check whether latest version of SQL Server Management Studio or SQL Server Data Tools is installed or not on the VM through which you are trying to connect to the database.

Next, confirm whether the application for which you are connecting to the database has service principal API permissions set or not. ‘Directory.Read.All’ application API permissions need to be added for the application with the assigned Azure AD Admin set as the consent. The Service principal for ‘SQL Managed Instance Contributor’ role should be set for the Azure AD Admin credentials.

For Azure Active Directory – Integrated authentication method, before connecting to the database, make sure you are entering the database name in the ‘Options’ section (bottom right corner) in the SSMS database connection dialog box. Also, check the connection string for parameters like ‘Active Directory Integrated’ and ‘Integrated Security=True’ for successful connection.

Please refer the below links for your reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/windows-azure-now-supports-federation-with-windows-server-active-directory/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview

Thanking you,